# Convert gas wall heater to inset fireplace

Tags: heating, fireplace, central-heating, heater, natural-gas

This wall heater is running on gas and has an electrical control. It is actually in front of the brick vent behind

[image]

[image]

This is in the attic as the vent connecting on top

[image]

Obviously this wall heater is very ugly so I want to change it to something more modern looking.

**What are my options?**

I am thinking:

1. Create a hole in wall and buy some gas in-wall fireplace. But I don't if this product exists and how the venting works.
2. Make this a regular gas fireplace without electrical control. But then the fire has to be turned on manually via some handle to turn on the gas. This is a big hassle.
3. Put in a furnace in the middle of the house and cover with a box and access door. Then run duct all around the house. This is the most expensive option and also take space right in the middle of the living room.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a recommendation since I never bought or installed one of these. Try searching for Woodland Direct or phone at 844-312-5159. I searched on-line and found this site. They seem to have just about everything you could possibly want. They have for example, a Kingsman ZV3600 zero clearance B-Vent gas fireplace Item #3580119 that may work for you. They have a long list of other possibilities, Or you can look up "wall mounted gas heaters or fireplaces".